# Why is my image in email template not properly aligned?

Tags: html, email, templates

How can I fix my margin and padding section in the email template to properly align my images in different columns  ?

I have inserted a full image and also partial code below. Thank you.

```html
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="middle" >
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%; 
        background-color: #ffffff; padding; 20px;"> 
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="display: inline-block; max-width: 270px; width: 100%;" align="center">
               
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sgw9MVx8/jug.png" alt="" style="max-width: 268px; width: 100%" border: 1px solid: #d5d5d5 />
                
                <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #000000"  > Jug </h3>
                
                <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; color: #444444; margin-bottom: 10px; "> 10% discounts</p>
                
            </td>
            
            <td style="display: inline-block; max-width: 20px; width: 100%" > 
               &nbsp;
                </td>
                
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="display: inline-block; max-width: 270px; width: 100%;" align="center">
               
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/CK9LqX9G/apple.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 268px; width: 100%" border: 1px solid: #d5d5d5 />
                
                <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #000000"  > Apple </h3>
                
                <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; color: #444444; margin-bottom: 10px; "> 10% discounts</p>
                
            </td>
        </tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Images resolution should be of the same size.